# What is global.asax used for?

Tags: asp.net

What is the purpose of the `global.asax` in ASP.NET?

Comment: Assuming you mean global.asax, [here's some info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2027ewzw(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Usually for general purpose questions like yours, I'd ask my favorite search engine first because sometimes you'll get the same answer here. In case you doubt that please see the first hit on this search:

http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enRO291RO303&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=global+ascx

And compare the answer there with the first answer you find here.

Answer (score 29):

> The Global.asax file, also known as the ASP.NET application file, is an optional file that contains code for responding to application-level and session-level events raised by ASP.NET or by HTTP modules. The Global.asax file resides in the root directory of an ASP.NET application. At run time, Global.asax is parsed and compiled into a dynamically generated .NET Framework class derived from the HttpApplication base class. ASP.NET is configured so that any direct URL request for the Global.asax file is automatically rejected; external users cannot download or view the code in it.
>   The Global.asax file is optional. You create it only if you want to handle application or session events.

(MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2027ewzw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Some application level events you can declared ..

For Example , you want to execute something while All session ends for that 
you can you global.asax file straight way .. There is a event Session_End