# What does ASAX stand for?

Tags: asp.net

There is a `Global.asax` file in the root of asp.net applications.

- What is the reason behind the extension naming?
- Can I create other files to use this extension? For what purpose?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085775/what-is-global-asax-used-for

Here is a better breakdown.
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/05/what-is-use-of-globalasax-file-in.html

You can make new Global.asax file, but really there is no purpose as only 1 can be loaded.

Comment: These are only covering the Global.asax not the whole extention.

Answer (score 4):

`Global.asax` extension [stands](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/315853-In-aspnet-globalasax-therewhat-asax.aspx) for:

> **A**ctive **S**erver **A**pplication E**x**tended

..and it has only one purpose, as stated in [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xaas8a2(v=vs.71).aspx):

> .. is an optional file that contains code for responding to
>   application-level events raised by ASP.NET or by HttpModules